# AJAX JavaScript form catch file download and get file info

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've created a script that catches a Captcha forms submission. The form will normally download a file (mixture of formats, I.E exe, zip, etc), the usual way (in chrome, shows download at the bottom, downloads into "downloads" directory.

I don't want the script to actually store the downloaded on the users computer, so I've edited the form submission to handle the download with AJAX, and store the files data in a variable. Another function then uploads this script to a PHP page.

**Is there any way to retrieve the information of the file that's downloading, file name, file type, etc?** It could, for example be called 'Application.1.2.zip', but I don't know how to retrieve this data from the AJAX request that downloads the file. The only reason I need this, is to get the file type, so I can store the file under the correct format on the second domain.

The current process attempts to download a file from domain A (any file format) with AJAX, store the file in a variable, then upload the file to domain B also using AJAX.

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content-Disposition HTTP header could be solution for you. From the W3C [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html):

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user requests that the content is saved to a file. This usage is derived from the definition of Content-Disposition in RFC 1806 [35].

```
content-disposition = "Content-Disposition" ":"
                          disposition-type *( ";" disposition-parm )
disposition-type = "attachment" | disp-extension-token
disposition-parm = filename-parm | disp-extension-parm
filename-parm = "filename" "=" quoted-string
disp-extension-token = token
disp-extension-parm = token "=" ( token | quoted-string )
```

An example is

```
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

This way, you can do it in one request.

In JavaScript you can extract the filename similar to this:

```
var disposition = httpRequest.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
var filename = disposition.substring(disposition.indexOf('=') + 1);
```

Comment: There must be some way to retrieve the file name / file type from the AJAX request? If the browser does it when it downloads it normally, surely something must be held in the request which tells the browser what file type is downloading? I've looked at retrieving the response headers, but from that I can only find content type, not file name / format.

Comment: Thank you for editing! - This works perfectly. I can retrieve this by adding the following to the onreadystatechange method of the ajax request object: var filename = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'); - You could then use something like String.split('"') and retrieving the returned arrays second indexed data e.g var filename = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split('"')[1];

Please append this to your answer to help out others viewing this. 
Many thanks! 
Dan.